# $a ∈ (Z/pZ)^*$ is called a cube if there exists $b ∈ (Z/pZ)^*$ such that $a = b^3$. If $p ≡ 2\pmod 3$, then all elements of $(Z/pZ)^*$ are cubes

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime.  An element $a ∈ (Z/pZ)^*$ is called a cube if there exists 
$b ∈ (Z/pZ)^*$  such that $a = b^3$.  If $p ≡ 2 \pmod 3$, show that all elements of  $(Z/pZ)^*$ are cubes.   If $p ≡ 1 \pmod 3$, how many elements of $(Z/pZ)^*$ are cubes?

Comment: Think about the map $x\to x^3$ defined on those groups.  What could the possible orders of the image and kernel be?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Do you think if you can show me how to obtain the kernel and the order of f(ℤ)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{Z}_p^∗$ be the multiplicative group of the field F. Find the kernel of the squaring homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}_p^∗→\mathbb{Z}_p^∗$, $f(x)=x^3$. Use that to find the order of the image $f(\mathbb{Z}_p^∗)$

- If $p\equiv 2 \mod 3$ then $f$ is one to one because $\varphi(p)=p-1$ is coprime to $3$ hence $|f(\mathbb{Z}_p^∗)|=p-1$ (there is no element of order $3$, so the equation $x^3=1$ has only one solution)
- If $p\equiv 1 \mod 3$ then $\forall a\in f(\mathbb{Z}_p^∗)$ we have $a^{\frac{p-1}{3}}=1$ and because there exist an element of order $p-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p^∗$ then there exists an elemnent of order $\frac{p-1}{3}$ in $f(\mathbb{Z}_p^∗)$ hence $|f(\mathbb{Z}_p^∗)|=\frac{p-1}{3}$